# Create a vector in C++ with constant values

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I want to create a vector by determining the size and the constant value which the vector has, e.g. a vector of the size 5 and only 3 as values.

```
vector = {3, 3, 3, 3, 3}
```

I only know how to create a vector with zero as value with `std::vector<int> vec(5)`;

Comment: Have you tried to constructor that accepts a count and a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a constructor that accepts a count and a value.

```
std::vector<int> v (5,3);
```

Will result in having a vector of a size 5 and 3 as a values `{3,3,3,3,3}`.

Comment: As it was already commented while i was writing this down apperantly.

Comment: There are different ways to construct a vector, i would suggest looking up the [cpp reference](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) to become familiar with them.

Comment: your link is to cplusplus.com. The cppreference link would be something like  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector#Example